# Bot-framework bot creating groupchat

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, groupchat

I have a bot-framework bot integrated to MS Teams, and I need it to create groupChats of members in it's team, with the bot in the chat as well.
Is there any way to achieve that?
I could not find any mention of creating or in any other way interacting with group chats using bots.

Comment: @Italy Davidson You can add an existing bot to a group chat but bot initiating to create a group chat with itself and other members is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Logic Apps or Power Automate flow. It has Teams actions that I think could help you ("Create a chat"). You could trigger the flow with an HTTP request that would contain necessary data!